# Is it possible to use the token that AD B2C is going to Issue within the Custom policies to call Rest techinical profile for authentication?

Tags: rest, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I have a REST API which is protected by AD B2C and I want to consume the API with in the custom policies. Is it possible to use the B2C token as a bearer token to call the api in the REST technical profile before returning or issuing the token to the relying party?

I have gone through the Microsoft documentation on how to call an API to generate a token and how to consume that between the technical profiles in ADB2C custom policies. But what I am expecting is to use the same JWT token that is going to issue by ADB2C between the user journeys or technical profiles. Is it possible to do that? if so, can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, the token isn't available to B2C itself during a custom policy/user journey flow and may not even be generated as the return value from an `/authorize` call.

You should instead have B2C make its own `client_credentials` call to itself to generate an access_token representing B2C as an app (without an authorised user present) and  have your API support that as an alternative means of authorisation.

I'd also caution against using the exact same API endpoints for both B2C and public  consumption. While you probably can, B2C has some [specific requirements when it comes to error responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#returning-validation-error-message) to ensure logging and messaging to users is correct. If you're in control of the APIs then I'd recommend having separate endpoints for B2C and public use, with both endpoints sharing the same underlying code but formatting requests and responses differently and secured with different types of tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Getting B2C to get a JWT from itself via client credentials and then using the JWT as a bearer token for an API is documented [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-the-client-credentials-flow-inside-of-azure-ad-b2c-12952e95d8cb).